# Autonomous vehicle lateral control

Tags: control-engineering, automotive-engineering, matlab, car, linear-motion

I am working on a control system for autonomous vehicles, i am using a kinematic bicycle model simulated on matlab simulink and the formula i used for the steering angle is given in the figures below along with the code and my simulink model:
[image: formula]

```
x=roadCenters(:,1);
y=roadCenters(:,2);

% Your data
t = 1:size(x)
 % Fit a third-degree polynomial to the x-coordinates
px = polyfit(t, x, 3);

   % Fit a third-degree polynomial to the y-coordinates
py = polyfit(t, y, 3);

   % Find the first derivative of x(t) and y(t)

   dx = polyder(px);
   dy = polyder(py);

   % Find the second derivative of x(t) and y(t)
   d2x = polyder(dx);
   d2y = polyder(dy);

  % Calculate the curvature
  k = abs(polyval(dx, t).*polyval(d2y, t) - polyval(dy, t).*polyval(d2x, t)) ./ (polyval(dx, 
  t).^2 + polyval(dy, t).^2).^(3/2);

  % the steering angle
  d=atan(L*k);

  % moving d to simulink

  t = (0:length(d)-1)'; % Create a time vector
  D= timeseries(d, t); % Create a timeseries object
```

[image]
Result :
[image: result]

Questions:

what is wrong with my path tracking ? i suspect :

-The data transfer from script to simulink isn't right and is giving insufficient data;

-The speed profile that i chose is not compatible with the path tracking .

[image: speed]

Comment: a single steering input on a bicycle results in it falling over, bicycles are steered by one input to lean the bike over and then input the other direction to keep it leaned over.  Automobiles have more than 2 wheels.

Comment: @TigerGuy `unicycle model`, `bicycle model`, `tricycle model` etc. are names given to certain types of models and need not require *balancing*; they are most likely only modelling *top view* of a vehicle and hence there aren't enough variables modelled for it to *lean* or *fall over*.

Comment: What are the red and blue lines in the XY plot? reference trajectory and actual trajectory? The red line ends in (1000, 400) while the blue line ends in (-400, 1000). This usually indicates either **(a)** `x` and `y` coordinates were flipped or **(b)** cross product of two vectors were done in the wrong order or **(c)** some angle was defined clockwise while it should have been anticlockwise (or input to a trigonometric function was flipped).

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the reason was a missing negative sign in `d=atan(L*k)`; i.e. `d=atan((-1)*L*k)`. By the way, what is `L`? Question has insufficient information IMO.